# Postgres NOT IN does not work as expected

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to add the below condition in my query to filter data.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dump
WHERE letpos NOT IN ('0', '(!)','NA','N/A') ;
```

I need only records with id 1,2,3 and 6. But the query does not return ids 3 and 6. I get only 1,2.

TABLE:

| id | name | letpos | num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | A | 60 |
| 2 | BBB | B |  |
| 3 | CCC |  | 50 |
| 4 | DDD | 0 |  |
| 5 | EEE | (!) | 70 |
| 6 | FFF |  | 70 |

I am not sure what is missing? Could anyone advise on how to resolve this?

-Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the row with `id = 3` the value of `letpos` is (I suspect) `NULL`, so the boolean expression in the `WHERE` clause is:

```
WHERE NULL NOT IN ('0', '(!)','NA','N/A');
```

The comparison of `NULL` with operators like `IN`, `NOT IN`, `=`, `>` etc always returns `NULL` and is never `TRUE`.
So you don't get this row in the results.

Check for `NULL` also in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dump 
WHERE letpos IS NULL
   OR letpos NOT IN ('0', '(!)', 'NA', 'N/A');
```